# What is checkpoint node HDFS? Why use it?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

I am new for hadoop so please give answer.  I know basic knowledge about name node and datanode.

Comment: We are not here to find/read documentation for you, or be your tutors.  We're here to help, but that doesn't include helping you be lazy.

Comment: would you like to check this out ? https://apptech-solution.blogspot.in/2016/08/what-is-big-data-it-is-broad-term-for.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Checkpoint Node fetches periodically fsimage and edits from the NameNode and merges them. The resulting state is called checkpoint. After this is uploads the result to the NameNode.

A Checkpoint Node was introduced to solve the drawbacks of the NameNode. The changes are just written to edits and not merged to fsimage during the runtime. If the NameNode runs for a while edits gets huge and the next startup will take even longer because more changes have to be applied to the state to determine the last state of the metadata.

There was also a similiar type of node called “Secondary Node” but it doesn’t have the “upload to NameNode” feature. So the NameNode need to fetch the state from the Secondary NameNode. It also was confussing because the name suggests that the Secondary NameNode takes the request if the NameNode fails which isn’t the case.

Hope this Helps!!!...